# 'int' object has no attribute - passing through __call__ to method in class

Tags: python, call

What this is:
A class uses to control game characters stats and interaction for both NPCs and players.

The **call** method was added to create mew "mob types" that can have their stat scaling controlled based on the player level.

I am trying to use the Mob.wyvern(player_level) method to create a "Wyvern" type NPC. In this case the code flows successfully until we try to modify a_wyvern.life using the self.playerlevel call.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\mystuff\Classes Game\Characters.py", line 74, in <module>
    a_wyvern = Mobs.wyvern(player_level)
  File "c:\Users\User\mystuff\Classes Game\Characters.py", line 36, in wyvern
    a_wyvern.life += a_wyvern.player_level
AttributeError: 'Mobs' object has no attribute 'player_level'
```

```
#Initializer, passing variables to all 
class Mobs():
    def __init__(self):
        self.life = 10
        self.atk = 2
        self.arm = 1
        self.name = villains.gen()
        self.playername = heroes.gen()
        self.type = type
            
    def __call__(self, player_level):
        self.player_level = player_level
        pass

    def attack(self, enemy):
        damage_amount = enemy.take_damage(self.atk)
        return damage_amount

    def take_damage(self, amount):
        damage_amount = (amount - self.arm)
        self.life -= damage_amount
        return damage_amount

    
    def wyvern(self):
        a_wyvern = Mobs()
        a_wyvern.type = "Wyvern"
        a_wyvern.life += self.player_level
        return a_wyvern
```

```
player_level = 20

a_wyvern = Mobs.wyvern(player_level)
a_wyvern.type
a_wyvern.life
a_wyvern.atk

print(a_wyvern.life)
print(a_wyvern.atk)
print(a_wyvern.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you've got the wrong idea about call. After you create an instance of a class, calling that instance like a function will be when `__call__` runs. Example:

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self, A):
        print('A', A)
        
    def __call__(self, B):
        print('B', B)

        
>>> a = A(5)
A 5
>>> a(4)
B 4
```

Call never actually runs in your scenario. Instead, you're bypassing `__init__` and `__call__`, to run a separate, initialization function, `wyvern`.

The problem here is one of two things. First, call never runs, despite it being *crucial* to `wyvern`'s execution. Second, you pass an integer into `wyvern`. `self` is a function variable, that automatically gets replaced by the instance of the class that each function is running in. An integer is a different class, that does not have an internal variable called `player_level`.

To sum up, your class initialization is messed up, which is creating a bunch of errors for you

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think understand what you're getting at here.

Would I better off just making a few if functions to classify types?

Comment: No, look into subclassing: https://www.codesdope.com/course/python-subclass-of-a-class/. You create a parent class, then create multiple smaller classes, that inherit from the upper class, and each smaller one can change a couple different things about the larger class, based upon per-animal features.

Comment: Also, if you're going to do that, look into properly using `__new__()`. Very powerful, *but only used for subclassing*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback everyone. Helped me learn a good bit!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to save the file since the error says `a_wyvern.life += a_wyvern.player_level`, but your code says `a_wyvern.life += self.player_level`.

Comment: You're not entirely wrong. I changed it a few ways to see if calling self. vs a_wyvern. would change the outcome.